# Python OpenCV : VideoCapture differences between Python 2.7 to Python 3.5

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, python-3.5

I'm connected to remote system through ssh, and trying to read frames using OpenCV VideoCapture in Python. The same code succeeds when using Python 2.7 and fails when using Python 3.5:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Python2.7:

```
print cap.isOpened() # prints True, further read() calls also return True
```

Python3.5:

```
print (cap.isOpened()) # prints False, and so are cap.open(), and of course cap.read().
```

What could cause such behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: Each of the Python versions has its own copy of the openCV binaries, and perhaps the two were built with different options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. OpenCV was installed from the sources.
The difference between Python 2 and 3 environment was, that for Python 3 opencv-python was *additionally* installed via pip3. A

```
pip3 uninstall opencv-python
```

solved it in my case.

Comment: This was exactly my issue. Thanks!